# Pappus centroid theorem and Hypercones.

Tags: volume, solid-of-revolution, centroid, convex-cone, hypercone

The volume of a straight cone in $\mathbb R^3$ is usually find adding the circular sections orthogonal to the height. If the base has radius $R$ and the height is $h$ we have:
$$
V_{C3}=\int_0^h \pi r^2 dz=\pi \int_0^h \frac{R^2}{h^2}z^2 dz=\pi \frac{R^2}{h^2} \frac{1}{3} h^3= \frac{1}{3}\pi R^2 h
$$
tha same result can be foud using the Pappus centroid theorem, rotating a right triangle with legs $h$ and $R$ around the cathetus $h$. Since the distance of the centroid from the axis of rotation is $R/3$, the theorem gives
$$V_{C3}=Ad=\frac{1}{2}Rh \cdot 2\pi\frac{R}{3}=\frac{1}{3}\pi R^2h$$

If we generalize such results to a hypercone in $\mathbb R^4$, the first procedure gives the result
$$
V_{C4}=\int_0^h\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3dz=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^h\left(\frac{R}{h}z \right)^3dz=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3h
$$
in accord to what we can find in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercone#Hypervolume) (and in other internet resources). And this result can be generalized to $n-$dimension :
$$
V_{Cn}=\frac{1}{n}V_{S(n-1)}h
$$
($V_{S(n-1)}$ is the volume of the hypersphere of dimension $n-1$).

To generalize te second procedure I use the generalized Pappus Theorem as formulated in this page of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem#In_n-dimensions):

*Volume of $n$-solid of revolution of species $p$
= (Volume of generating $(n-p)$ solid)
$\times$  (Surface area of $p-$sphere traced by the
$p-$th centroid of the generating solid)*

so, using the same triangle but rotating it on the surface of a $3-$sphere, I found:
$$ V_{C4}=Rh \cdot 4\pi\left( \frac{R}{3} \right)^2=\frac{4}{9}\pi R^3h$$
that is a different volume  (and in $n-$dimension I have an analogous result).

Where is my reasoning wrong? I suspect that I have a misinterpretation of the generalized Pappus Theorem or that the  rotation of a triangle around a $(n-1)-$sphere gives a different kind of cone with respect to the usual cone in n-dimension. If so, where I can find a classification of such kind of cones?

Comment: (+1) Just a couple of immediate impressions (time doesn't permit more at the moment): 1. The volume of both the unit sphere and unit ball in four-space are rational multiples of $\pi^2$, so something is awry with the cone volume (maybe just a missing factor of $\pi$?). 2. Rotations (orthogonal transformations of determinant $1$) in dimension greater than three work differently than three-dimensional intuition suggests. That's not to say Wikipedia is wrong, only that the language of "rotation" may be misleading.

Comment: thank you @Andrew. The base of the 4-cone is a 3-spere so the factor $\pi$ (and not $\pi^2$) is correct.

Comment: My oops; you're right, of course.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Yours doesn't seem to be the same hypercone defined in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercone#Construction) as "*the hypervolume swept out by a tetrahedron standing upright in the 4th direction as it rotates freely about its base in the 3D hyperplane on which it rests*". That said, all this is not exactly my cup of tea, and I am not sure what a *p-th centroid* even is.

Comment: Thank you @dxiv.  I also think that the problem is that. But I don't quite understand what it means  "...it rotates freely about its base in the 3D hyperplane ..."   and I can't find a source where the classification of cones in n-dimension is explained and discussed.

Comment: In the hope it's helpful, the wikipedia page on Pappus's theorem references a [1958 book](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.220891/page/n161/mode/2up) by D.M.Y. Sommerville on $n$-dimensional geometry; the link here points to a copy from Osmania University at the Internet Archive. (Still trying to Really Understand understand the definitions myself....)

Comment: that seems useful. Tank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl; dr: The formulas work out for a cone of height $h$ and base radius $R$ in four-space. The volume is indeed
\begin{align*}
  \tfrac{1}{3}\pi R^{3}h &= (\tfrac{1}{2}Rh)(\tfrac{2}{3}\pi R^{2}) \\
  &= (\text{area of generating triangle})(\text{area of sphere through the triangle's $p$-centroid})
\end{align*}
for a suitable "$p$-centroid." This point is not the usual geometric centroid, however: Its location depends on $p$.

---

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Vol}{Vol}$**Generalities**: To start, here's a brief account of "volumes of rotation of species $p$." (This is doubtless the content of [Sommerville's book](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.220891/page/n161/mode/2up), but Sommerville's notation is not how I visualize the geometry.) Let $p$ and $m$ be positive integers, and let $n = m + p + 1$. To describe what is meant by "revolving a region $D \subset \Reals^{m+1}$ about $p$-dimensional spheres," let $SO(p+1)$ denote the group of Euclidean rotations of $\Reals^{p+1}$, and decompose Cartesian $n$-space as
\begin{align*}
  \Reals^{n} &= \Reals^{m} \times \Reals \times \Reals^{p} \\
  &= \Reals^{m} \times \underbrace{\Reals^{p+1}}_{\text{$SO(p+1)$ acts}} \\
  &= \underbrace{\Reals^{m+1}}_{\text{$D$ lives here}} \times \Reals^{p}.
\end{align*}
If $\Vec{x} \in \Reals^{m}$, $\Vec{y}_{0} \in \Reals^{p}$, $r$ is real, and $\Vec{y} = (r, \Vec{y}_{0}) \in \Reals^{p+1}$, the general element of $\Reals^{n}$ may be written
$$
(\Vec{x}, \Vec{y}) = (\Vec{x}, r, \Vec{y}_{0}).
$$
We're arranging that $D$ is contained in the half-space of $\Reals^{m+1}$ where $r \geq 0$ and $\Vec{y}_{0} = \Vec{0}$. A rotation $A \in SO(p+1)$ acts by
$$
(\Vec{x}, \Vec{y}) \mapsto (\Vec{x}, A\Vec{y});
$$
the orbit of the point $(\Vec{x}, r, \Vec{0}) \in D$ is a $p$-sphere of radius $r$, specifically $\{\Vec{x}\} \times S^{p}(r) \subset \{\Vec{x}\} \times \Reals^{p+1}$.

Under this action, a volume element $d\Vec{x}\, dr$ of $D$ at $(\Vec{x}, r, \Vec{0})$ sweeps an infinitesimal volume
$$
\Vol_{p} S^{p}(r)\, d\Vec{x} = (\Vol_{p} S^{p}) r^{p}\, d\Vec{x}.
$$
The volume swept by revolving $D$ is the integral over $D$,
$$
\Vol_{n}[SO(p+1)(D)] = \Vol_{p} S^{p} \int_{D} r^{p}\, d\Vec{x}.
$$

This framework reduces to that of calculus if $p = m = 1$: In Cartesian coordinates $(x, r, y)$, the region $D$ lies in the half-plane $r \geq 0$ and $y = 0$; the group $SO(p + 1) = SO(2)$ revolves the $(r, y)$-plane about $\Reals^{m}$, a.k.a. the $x$-axis.

If we *define*
$$
\bar{r}^{p} = \int_{D} r^{p}\, d\Vec{x}\bigg/\int_{D} d\Vec{x}
= \frac{\Vol_{n}[SO(p+1)(D)]}{\Vol_{p} S^{p} \Vol_{m+1}(D)},
$$
then $\bar{r}$ is (by fiat, see Note at the bottom) the distance from the $p$-centroid to $\Reals^{m}$. Pappus' theorem is a formal triviality:
\begin{align*}
  \Vol_{n}[SO(p+1)(D)] &= (\Vol_{p} S^{p}) \bar{r}^{p} \Vol_{m+1}(D) \\
  &= \Vol_{p} S^{p}(\bar{r}) \Vol_{m+1}(D),
\end{align*}
the $p$-dimensional volume of the sphere of radius $\bar{r}$ times the $(m + 1)$-dimensional volume of $D$.

---

**The four-dimensional cone**: Here $m = 1$ and $p = 2$. The region $D$ may be taken to be the triangle $0 \leq x \leq h$ and $0 \leq r \leq Rx/h$. The $2$-centroid (really, its distance $\bar{r}$ from the axis) satisfies
$$
\bar{r}^{2} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}Rh} \int_{0}^{h} \int_{0}^{Rx/h} r^{2}\, dr\, dx
= \frac{2R^{2}}{3h^{4}} \int_{0}^{h} x^{3}\, dx
= \frac{R^{2}}{6}.
$$
The sphere of radius $\bar{r}$ has area $4\pi \bar{r}^{2} = \frac{2}{3}\pi R^{2}$, so as claimed above,
\begin{align*}
  (\text{area of generating triangle})(\text{area of sphere through $p$-centroid})
  &= (\tfrac{1}{2}Rh)(\tfrac{2}{3}\pi R^{2}) \\
  &= \tfrac{1}{3}\pi R^{3}h \\
  &= \text{volume of the (hyper-)cone}.
\end{align*}

---

**Note**: I don't see a natural mechanical interpretation of $\bar{r}$ Probabilistically, $\bar{r}^{p}$ is the mean of $r^{p}$, the $p$th power of the distance function from the "axis" (i.e., from $\Reals^{m}$). That is, $\bar{r}$ is the $p$-norm of the distance function $r$ over $D$, computed with respect to $(m + 1)$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you. I'm studying your answer. Especially what is $\bar r$ and what has to do with the usual centroid of a figure (a simplex in our case).

Comment: The "$p$-centroid" of a region (such as the triangle) is a point $(\bar{\mathbf{x}}, \bar{r})$ in $\mathbf{R}^{m+1}$; that is, $\bar{r}$ is the distance from the $p$-centroid to the "axis" $\mathbf{R}^{m}$. When $p = 1$ we recover the ordinary centroid: The region being revolved lies in the $(x, r)$-plane, $\bar{r}$ is the $r$-component of the usual centroid. <> In a sense this answer effectively uses Pappus's theorem to _define_ the $p$-centroid, but that also seems to be what Sommerville does.